# Saving data in a for loop in dynamoDB AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have to save data in 6 tables in dynamoDB AWS, can I put a 'for' loop and save one by one as shown below :-

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDB);
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
mapper.save(<TABLE 1 DATA>)
// and loop and save data in every table
}
```

Does it looks fine or it can create some problem as I am doing data base operation in loop?
My tables are very small(5 columns)

Thanks
Kailash

Answer (score 1):

Running in the for loop is a bad idea and you can use the batch write item api.  `dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(TableWriteItems... yourMultipleTableWriteItems)`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to download the data from the table into a local file, like CSV, for example, you can use this CLI tool https://github.com/zshamrock/dynocsv to export data from your table into the CSV file.